# How to send Socket details through a Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a Java application in which I need to pass details of a Socket object to remotely connected computer through a Socket... I tried it by passing the socket object in object output stream. But as "Socket" is not "serializable" it didn't work...
Can anyone help me please? Or tell me whether it is possible or not...

Thank you...

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a through another socket? The socket represents a connection between your machine and another - are you trying to create a proxy?

Comment: I would expect a socket to be something specific to the machine it is running on. Therefore sending it to a different machine seems not useful. I guess you should extract the required information (for example target URL etc) from the socket, send this information and let the remote computer create a new socket with that information.

Comment: My main idea is to get the input and Output Stream of that Socket... Actually am trying to link two different remote connection's Socket via this server's socket... Please let me know is this a good idea? Or I should think something else... Or is there any another way to do it?

Comment: Can you send a telephone over a phone call? Can you fax a fax machine? Your question doesn't make sense. Suppose you tell us about the *problem* you're trying to solve, instead of what you imagine the solution to be.

Comment: Okay I got it...Thank you EJP... But please can you provide me a solution how to connect two Sockets keeping a Server's Socket in middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the solution at your hand.

If you (the server) have 2 opened sockets, one from A and another from B all you have to do is:

What is read from A send it to B and what is read from B send it to A.

When socket A or socket B is closed (or has an error) you (the server) close both socket and the conversation is over. To deal with this scenario, you need to use **select** or another non-blocking mechanism to see which socket has data to be read and act accordingly. I would recommended to use a separate **thread** to do this job, so the server will be free to attend more clients.

Comment: Thank you so much ja_mesa... You were very helpful to me... :)